# Validate xml mime type in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a validator set up to check if the document we upload is an XML file

```php
if ($request->input('action') == 'upload_document') {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'file' => 'bail|required|mimes:application/xml,xml|max:10000',
        ]
    );
}
```

But when I do my upload, this validator triggers me an error "File must e of type application/xml,xml" even when I drop a real XML file with a .xml extension.

I have in my php.ini config extension=php_fileinfo.dll of course

Comment: Guessing the webserver is set to `text/xml` which the most common mime type setting for `xml` nowdays.

Comment: i did tried and it is sadly not working with text/xml too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the XML provided by an external company is not respecting the proper XML standard.

As it is not on my hands, I won't reformat it and I will have to manage it as text only. So I guess I can't use a validator in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Note that mime type validation instruct Laravel to read the content of the file to determine its type, so changing an image extension from `.jpg` to `.xml` will not trick it

From the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-mimes)

**mimes:*foo,bar*,...**

The file under validation must have a MIME type corresponding to one of the listed extensions.

#### Basic Usage Of MIME Rule

```php
'photo' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
```

Even though you only need to specify the extensions, this rule actually validates against the MIME type of the file by reading the file's contents and guessing its MIME type.

A full listing of MIME types and their corresponding extensions may be found at the following location: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

So make sure your file is an actual valid xml file (try this with phpunit.xml) from your Laravel project

```php
Route::post('/', function (Request $request) {
    if ($request->input('action') == 'upload_document') {
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'file' => 'bail|required|mimes:application/xml,xml|max:10000',
            ]
        );
        $validator->validate();
        dd('the file is valid');
    }
});
```

And a form like this

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input name="action" value="upload_document">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
@error('file')
{{ $message }}
@enderror
```

Result:

```
"the file is valid"
```

But when testing with `image.xml`

```
The file must be a file of type: application/xml, xml.
```

#### Alternatively, you can validate by extension

```php
Route::post('/', function (Request $request) {
    if ($request->input('action') == 'upload_document') {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => [
                'bail',
                'required',
                'max:10000',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    if ($value->getClientMimeType() !== 'text/xml') {
                        $fail($attribute.'\'s extension is invalid.');
                    }
                },
            ]
        ]);
        dd('the file is valid');
    }
});
```

Now an image file with the `xml` extension passes the validation

See [using closures for custom validation](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#using-closures)

Comment: Thanks for this long post, however the first solution is triggering the same error than my way of using validator

Comment: Include the XML file you're trying to validate in your question

Comment: and the second solution by extension is not providing any validator object and the validate of request just provides me an array with a file inside it, but I don't know if that means the validator was ok or not and I don't have any status for this callback of validate.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/transfer/cap_pid_ft%3AAAAAABgkttw-2N1WgOtaQRiZpyg-TFzYUQx4F7nKC8DI5-4lUmJE8rA

Comment: The mime type of that file is 'text/xml', and it passes validation on my machine, the problem is **NOT** in your code

Comment: Sadly it is not an issue from "my" file but the file that some partners provide me, and I don't have a hand on this. 
Anyway thanks for the work you did

Answer (score 0):

For those who try to pass xml extension on Laravel 5 (like me).
This will work with other additional extensions also.

Since Laravel ExtensionGuesser allows to add custom guesser via method register we do the folowing.

1. Make new class with own extensions array. I've made it exdending the original one so it corresponds the interface. I've put it to Helpers folder.

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\MimeTypeExtensionGuesser;

/**
 * Provides a best-guess mapping of mime type to file extension.
 */
class PriorExtensionGuesser extends MimeTypeExtensionGuesser
{
    /**
     * Addition to pretty old map of mime types and their default extensions.
     *
     * @see http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types
     */
    protected $defaultExtensions = array(
        'text/xml' => 'xml',
    );

}
```

2. In you controller (don't forget use statement):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\MimeType\ExtensionGuesser;

public function store (Request $request) {

        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {

            $guesser = ExtensionGuesser::getInstance(); //take the guesser who will guess
            $guesser->register(new \App\Helpers\PriorExtensionGuesser()); //add own guesser

            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

                'file' => 'file|mimes:txt,xls,xlsx,csv,xml|max:32768',

            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
.....
```

So now guesser checks our array in Prior* class then goes to original one.